# From Fullcalendar v3 to fullcalendar6

Tags: html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

Last year I found a Template based on Fullcalendar v3 and I costumize it based on the direction my boss gave me. Now I'm doing an upgrade to fullcalendar6 following the documentation but I'm having some trouble understanding

In my old code I had this `var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');` to get the view of the calendar, but I read that getView is deprecated and
In the V4 release it's written this

> access the Calendar’s view property instead

But I couldn't find the equivalent-ish.

I need it to get the start of the month (for that I read that I need to change **intervalStart** to **currentStart** but I'm missing the view part):

My old code:

```
var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
var start = view.intervalStart._d;
var monthS = start.getMonth();
```

Doc I found but coudnt' understand -> https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-object

I create this quesiton because I saw that the question here on SO refer to getView old Method.

---

**calendar.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

/*some customization of fullcalendar*/

    
    dateClick: function(event, date) {
       /*code*/
    },

    
    eventClick: function(event){
        /*code*/    
    });

    calendar.render();

   
document.getElementById("test").onclick = function() {exportTableToExcel()};
    function exportTableToExcel(){
        var username = '<?php echo $_SESSION["nome"]; ?>';
        var view = calendar.view;
        var start = view.currentStart;
        const month = start.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
        var year = new Date(start).getFullYear();
        
        var tab_text = '<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">';
        tab_text = tab_text + '<head><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet>';

        tab_text = tab_text + '<x:Name>Ore_'+month+'_'+year+'_'+username+'</x:Name>';
        tab_text = tab_text + '<x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes></x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>';
        tab_text = tab_text + '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml></head><body>';

        tab_text = tab_text + "<table border='2px'>";
        tab_text = tab_text + $('#table2').html();
        tab_text = tab_text + '</table></body></html>';

        var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';


       $('#test').attr('href', data_type + ', ' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
       $('#test').attr('download', 'Ore_'+month+'_'+year+'_'+username+'.xls');

    };
    
});
```

Basically I'm having trouble on this last function *exportTableToExcel()* where I have

> var view = calendar.view;

I also tried with

> var view = $('#calendar').view

with no success

Comment: you want the [get/setters](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dynamic-options)?

Comment: I need this -> [calendarView](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-view) but it gives me the error **view is undefined**

Comment: this is how you inicialize the [fullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals) with `new FullCalendar.Calendar(` .. then you access with `getOption` on the fist link.

Comment: @francisco like this?  `var view = calendar.getOption('view');`

Comment: I tried the one wrote in my last comment and it says getOption is not a function. But I wrote it the same as in the example

Comment: No you would write `var view = calendar.view` (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-view), not getOption. It's a property of the calendar itself, not a configuration option

Comment: @ADyson Okau. As I thought at the beginning; but still it's gives me error saying calendar is undefined even if I have inizialize fullcalendar as the doc says

Comment: You're probably accessing it out of scope then. If you need help with that, please provide a [mre] of the issue in your question.

Comment: I add it. If u maybe need something else pls tell me. Thanks you

Comment: Thanks. `calendar.view()` is wrong, it should be `calendar.view` as we showed you before. It's a property, not a function.

Comment: Actually now that you make me notice I wrote the code wrong; in my source I actually have **calendar.view** I found what the error was: basically I have to create the function before **calendar.render();** Now I'm gonna answer this question with this solution U gave me because it was the right one but coudnt found out anywhere

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade from fullcalendar v03 to fullcalendar v06 to get the view is:

```
var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
```

to

```
var view = calendar.view;
```

You have to do it before rendering the calendar.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, and I can't reproduce any such problem - your original code (as shown in the question) works fine - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/poZVBJZ . Of course, if this code isn't the same as your real code, then that might have something to do wtih it.

Comment: I dont know what to say, I copy paste the same exact code (except for the **view()**) that before copying paste was commented for some try I was doing